# Dell switches, LAG config, ports stay lit when device powered off

Tags: dell, high-availability, lag

I have two Dell switches configured in a stack (with stacking cables).  I have four ports on each unit in the stack configured in two separate LAGs as follows:

```
Unit 1/P1: LAG1
Unit 1/P2: LAG1
Unit 1/P3: LAG2
Unit 1/P4: LAG2

Unit 2/P1: LAG1
Unit 2/P2: LAG1
Unit 2/P3: LAG2
Unit 2/P4: LAG2
```

Connected into the ports/LAGs I have two firewalls, each with four interfaces bonded.  All four interfaces on FW1 are connected to LAG1 and the four interfaces on FW2 are connected to LAG2.

The above is for a high-availability failover setup using keepalived.

The failover happens just fine if I simulate a failure by stopping keepalived on FW1.  The failover also occurs when I power off FW1, however after about a minutes, the connection becomes unstable.  If I power FW1 back on, the connection stabilises again (it doesn't matter if FW1 is booted to just BIOS or even the GRUB menu; as long as it is powered on, the connection stabilises, even if the floating IPs remain on FW2)

What is odd, however, is that when FW1 is powered off, the four LAG ports it is connected in to remain powered on, as though there is connectivity detected.  Even if I unplug the power cable from the back of FW1, the LAG ports remain lit.  I beleiev this is at least a contributor of the unstable connection issue, if not the actual cause itself (for whatever reason)

I am wonder if anyone might know if maybe there is a setting I missed in the LAG setup that would shut the ports down when the device connected to those ports is off?  I don't recall having to set something like that before, but you never know.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Model of Dell switches?

Comment: I would guess this is a FW issue, rather than a switch issue.  You certainly need more info about both to come up with any sort of answer.